# jQuery Resizable disable on parent only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a few controls contained in divs on it. We allow the user to go into a sort of Edit mode and then they can move and resize the controls to their liking, including the main div that holds all the controls.

Without going into too much detail, I have resizable enabled on the main div and all the children. At a certain point I want to disable only the Parent's resizable while leaving all the children as is.

But if I tell jQuery to disable resizable on the parent it will automatically do the same for its children.

I can work around it by destroying all the resizable for everything, and then just redo it for the just the children, but I would rather want to enable and disable as needed instead.

So if I call `$('#SomeID').resizable('disable')` it should not effect any of the children controls.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You have more chances to receive an anwser if you provide your code.

Comment: How did you get on with the answer below Nick, which was posted on the same day as your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using JQueryUI (because of your resizable method):

If you want to remove the resizable feature from a specific element you can do that by just deleting the related class from your element

```js
$(document).on('click', '.child', function() { 
 $(this).removeClass('ui-resizable');
});

$(document).on('click', '.container', function() { 
 $(this).removeClass('ui-resizable');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").resizable();
  $(".child").resizable();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you click an element it removes only the resizable feature of that specific element.